# ActionScript 3 scrolling issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to make a google maps style interface for a design project. I've got the drag/drop and zoom functions working, but I also want to make it react to gestures on a trackpad (macbook). I assumed 'listening' to the event.delta of a MouseEvent would do the trick, but somehow it's not working. So what's wrong with my code?

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, onMouseWheelEvent);
function onMouseWheelEvent(event:MouseEvent):void {
    tafelOrigineel_mc.y += event.delta;
}
```

I have loaded the flash MouseEvents earlier in the document, so that shouldn't be the problem. After I got this working, I will try to use it on the x-axis too. Is that possible with the MOUSE_WHEEL eventlistener?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long time problem regarding flash player on MacOS.

MOUSE_WHEEL event won't dispatch on MacOS. Though there are some workarounds involving the use of JavaScript to detect the use of the wheel (over the entire flash content), if it isn't a issue, try checking one of those.

There is a list in this blog post:

http://www.impossibilities.com/v4/2009/03/06/flash-mousewheel-implementations-for-mac-os-x/

Comment: As mentioned this is an oldy.  I think the work-around essentially go something like, write some javascript, capture the event using javascript, stop the event from doing it's default thing in the web browser, use an ExeternalInterface.addCallback to register a callback to a function, in the javascript method call the Flash callback.